# Web Audio API XMLHTTP Request No Access Allowed

Tags: javascript, nginx, web-audio-api, crossdomain-request.js

```
function init() {
    // Fix up prefixing
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new AudioContext();

// BufferLoader takes: (context, url, callback)
bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
  context,
  [
    'http://localhost:8085/atari_sound.mp3',
    'http://localhost:8085/mario_walk.wav',
    'http://localhost:8085/bomb.mp3'
  ],
  finishedLoading
  );

bufferLoader.load();
}
```

So I'm using nginx to run localhost:8085, and I keep trying to load these sounds but I keep getting this error:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:// localhost:8085/bomb.mp3. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

I understand that javascript won't do crossdomain requests but it worked before and now all of a sudden it isnt working. Any ideas?

Comment: Do the other files throw a similar error?

Comment: Nope. These are the only ones I load up. It's strange because I haven't changed anything else and up until recently it was working just fine

Comment: Can you access http:// localhost:8085/bomb.mp3 directly?